# Why is my phone media query being ignored over my tablet query

Tags: css

Heya not sure why this is doing this but my page looks great on desktop and tablet but the phone size query never gets shown and i dont know why. Heres the stripped CSS:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 0.25fr;
    grid-gap: 2px 2px;
    grid-template-areas: ". shop resource help buttons badges" ". aghlogo about phone address badges" "copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright";
    margin-top: 10vh;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    margin-right: 2vw;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        height: 100%;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: .5fr .5fr .5fr .5fr .5fr .5fr .5fr .5fr .5fr .5fr;
        grid-gap: 1px 1px;
        grid-template-areas: "buttons" "shop" "resource" "help" "badges" "aghlogo" "about" "phone" "address" "copyright";
        text-align: center;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: 10%;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: .5fr .5fr .5fr .5fr;
        grid-gap: 1px 1px;
        grid-template-areas: "buttons shop resource help" "badges badges badges badges" "aghlogo about phone address" "copyright copyright copyright copyright";
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is because min width 1023 is overwritten the min width 768. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the (max-width: ..) and (min-width: ..) values to set a minimum width and a maximum width:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 768px) {}
```

Hope it solved it.

Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the screen sizes are correct?
You can find a [list of media queries here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

You can then test in your browser. In Chrome, `right-click` then select `Inspect` then click on this icon:

[image]

Comment: yeah the screen width for iphone 6/7/8 in inspector is 736px so that should be displaying my max-width 768px media query but it still uses the 1023px media query and im not sure why.